# Can you add child controls to a HtmlGenericControl?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, controls

I have a very simple operation where I try to add a HtmlGenericControl  to another HtmlGenericControl :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
  HtmlGenericControl p = new HtmlGenericControl("p");

  div.Controls.Add(p);//exception occurs
}
```

An exception is thrown in the debugger only - the page itself renders as though nothing had happened. However something definitely does happen, as in a larger portion of code, controls are not being rendered as they should.

[image]

The actual exception is:

```
{InnerText = '((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)(div)).InnerText' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'}
```

I can't understand why this is happening, as you should be able to add controls to each other in this manner.

Note that from the first answer, I tried again with IDs but it still doesn't work:

[image]

I have some more information.
When using a Placeholder control as the parent, there is no exception:

```
protected void Page_Init()
{
  PlaceHolder ph = new PlaceHolder();
  HtmlGenericControl p = new HtmlGenericControl("p");

  ph.Controls.Add(p);//no problem
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> "An exception is thrown in the debugger only - the page itself renders
>   as though nothing had happened."

That's fine in that InnerText won't work if there are child controls; that is by design because it doesn't want to render the whole hierarchy of controls at that time for various performance, lifecycle, and side affect reasons.

> "... something definitely does happen, as in a larger portion of code,
>   controls are not being rendered as they should."

What does that mean? What is rendering incorrectly in the "larger portion" of code? My guess is that is a problem somewhere else and not related to what you have in your question here.

So I think you're fine. Ignore the exception in InnerText on the parent control. You need to ask a new Question regarding whatever issue you are having with the "larger portion" of your code.

Answer (score 1):

i think an easy solution to avoid this error can be to render the child HtmlGenericControl into a string and then adding it to the parents inside the InnerHtml attribute. something like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl parent = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
HtmlGenericControl child = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter twr = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
child.RenderControl(twr);
string rendered=stringWriter.ToString().Replace("\r","").Replace("\n","").Replace("\t","");
parent.InnerHtml =  rendered;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a panel first. then you can create child HtmlGenericControl and then parent HtmlGenericControl and then you can add the parent control into the panel. for example:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server" ></asp:Panel>

//parent
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div"); 

//child 
HtmlGenericControl p = new HtmlGenericControl("p");      

// adding child control to parent control.
div.Controls.Add(p);

div.Visible = true;

//adding parent control to panel
panel.Controls.Add(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am incorrect, please see comment by Jon Adams.

<strike>I would suspect it has something to do with the controls not having IDs set yet. I could be wrong... but here's how to set IDs, if that is the problem.</strike>

[HtmlGenericControl and id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496448/htmlgenericcontrol-and-id)

Comment: Incorrect. IDs are only used for external code to reference the objects. Internally, the rendering process iterates across child controls and will assign IDs automatically when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just my small assumption:

> protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
>
> HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
>     div.InnerText = "";
>
> HtmlGenericControl p = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
>
> div.Controls.Add(p);//exception occurs }

Answer (score 0):

I just did a little [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innertext.aspx) research. Apparently you are not allowed to use more than one HtmlContainerControl.

*Exception----------Condition*

**HttpException**---There is more than one HTML server control.

Although you may create more than one HtmlContainerControl ... Still looking into this matter. Any way, **no exception** will be thrown when executing this piece of code

```
    try
    {
        HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div.ID = "div1";
        HtmlGenericControl p = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
        p.ID = "p1";
        div.Controls.Add(p);
        div.InnerText = "sep";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
```

Perhaps it is only a debugger message for VS.. not quite sure about this... I am going to re-edit my answer later ..

Answer (score 0):

If you try to do this

```
string text = div.InnerText;
```

you'll get next exception

> Cannot get inner content of id1 because the contents are not literal.

which tells that you can not see generated html in this way.

Answer (score 0):

you may

create asp:Panel and it rendered as div exactly and add all controls you want inside it

or

div.InnerHtml += p.InnerHtml

this will add your render html of p to the div